# Run .NET 4 code from script component SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis, bids

I need to run custom code from SSIS script component. As I know it supports .NET 2-3.5.
Can you tell me please a workaround of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a web service/WCF service to call the .NET 4.0 custom code and invoke the custom code from the `Script Component` through the service.

Here is a [**link**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/07/08/how-to-configure-an-ssis-package-to-access-a-web-service-using-wcf.aspx) that shows `How to Configure an SSIS Package to Access a Web Service using WCF`. It is not exactly the same as what you are looking for but I hope that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it as an .exe and run it in an 'Execute Process Task'

Comment: I need to run it in context of DataFlow task.

Comment: So, use it in place of a 'SSIS Script Component'. Connect this up to your data flow task.